# Language parser library written in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, parser-generator, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking for a language parser **written in PHP**.

The goal is to **read a custom language**, not read PHP code.

Basically, I want to specify a language syntax, give a code snippet and get back a structure representing it. Then I can traverse that structure to execute the code snippet. I believe the structure will be an *AST*, but I don't know if this is the only option (I am not intimate with parsers and their vocabulary).

I had a look at the [Doctrine DQL parser](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php) but it doesn't seem like a generic language parser.

Comment: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/parser-and-lexer-generators-for-php/ - there is also one on sourceforge but too lazy to search the link for you. you can start with lemon, it's normally good for an easy start but don't fall dead when you see the file-size of the generated PHP class.

Comment: People wanting to close the question, please explain

Comment: @hakre Interesting, so Lemon generates a parser written in PHP? I'll look into it. I'd rather have a generic parsing PHP library instead though (it avoids going back and forth with Lemon if the language evolves).

Comment: If I remember right, then yes. Here is the sourceforge link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lime-php/ - If you're looking for something PHP on-the-fly, there is [Phlexy](https://github.com/nikic/Phlexy) for a PHP lexer it's by NikiC who also uses it in [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

Comment: @hakre Amazing! Phlexy is exactly what I was looking for! Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it before the question is closed (for a mysterious reason but people seem to fancy that idea)

Comment: not mysterious, because it's normally accepted you do some little research ;) asking for libaries is a bit moot. so if you don't mind, come back in half a year and update this question / answer a little as you see fit.

Comment: I really searched, and really didn't find anything. The only thing (in PHP) that I found was Doctrine's parser (too specific) and NikiC's PHP parser (but I didn't bother reading into that because I thought that it was implemented like the real PHP parser, i.e. without AST :|)... I realize I should have :)

Comment: Yes, I know that it's hard to search for that. But for other users this question might look like just another question for: Which library? You know inside the PHP tag there is so much crap along the day, you can't believe it.

Comment: PHP isn't generally used to implement custom language processors (which is why you see a dearth of tools for this in PHP).  Is there a reason you insist on using PHP?

Comment: @IraBaxter I write a PHP library for PHP applications

Comment: I just have the same need :) migrate between languages back and forth. 
Could you share how did your quest end up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete list, if you're looking for PHP runtime lexer/parsers, one exceptional project is [Phlexy](https://github.com/nikic/Phlexy) by NikiC.

You can find a use-case inside [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) as well written by him. That is a parser for the PHP language with an abstract syntax tree (AST), partially generated from a grammar file.

I never managed it to get that far yet, from my own research over the years, there are not many such projects in PHP userspace, and these two libraries from NikiC are really a very good example.

If you're looking for a lexer that follows more the flex rules, I have written one in [XDOM](https://github.com/hakre/XDOM) that lexes CSS selector syntax, it's also with a parser but the parser is not based on a grammar file even though it exists in the CSS specs. The lexer is based on a .lex file.

Comment: 2019 update: There are 3 tools in the answer in irrelevant order. Nowadays the php-parser is the best tool and standard to use, well adopted by PHP community that builds many tools on its shoulders.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to parse PHP code; he wants to parse a custom language. Apparently PHP-Parser uses [a forked version of kmyacc](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/624f71fa6f9cf0708d9e8625b3bea564c5fe7a24/grammar/rebuildParsers.php#L16) that somehow targets PHP via a template.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly php has a library to do a lexer/parser:
http://php.net/manual/en/parle.examples.php
For Windows, looks like you can grab a pre-compiled binary.
http://php.net/manual/en/parle.installation.php 
says versions available here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parle/